# TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__' in Flask using SQLite3

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

EDIT: I found out what was causing NoneType error, sorry for bothering you.

In my code I want to open my records.db and get last index in it and then use this index as name of uploaded file (increased by one), but my method works only with normal python script, in Flask i get NoneType error..

Here is my code:

```
import os
import datetime
import subprocess
import sqlite3
import sys
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, g
from werkzeug import secure_filename

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = 'uploads'
app.config['ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS'] = set(['txt', 'gro', 'doc', 'docx'])

DATABASE = 'records.db'

def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and \
           filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1] in app.config['ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS']

def get_db():
    db = getattr(g, '_database', None)
    if db is None:
        db = g._database = sqlite3.connect(DATABASE)
    return db

def get_id():
    cur = get_db().cursor()
    cur.execute('SELECT id FROM Records ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;')
    number = cur.fetchone()
    filenum = int(number[0])
    return filenum + 1

@app.teardown_appcontext
def close_connection(exception):
    db = getattr(g, '_database', None)
    if db is not None:
        db.close()

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/upload', methods = ['POST'])
def upload():
    num = get_id()
    file = request.files['file']
    if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
        file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], num.filename))
        subprocess.call(['python', '/home/martyna/Dropbox/programowanie/project_firefox/topologia.py', 'uploads/'+num.filename])
        return "Thank you for uploading"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

And this:         `filenum = int(number[0])` causes my error. I would appreciate any help.

Full error trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/martyna/Dropbox/programowanie/project_firefox/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/martyna/Dropbox/programowanie/project_firefox/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "/home/martyna/Dropbox/programowanie/project_firefox/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/martyna/Dropbox/programowanie/project_firefox/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/martyna/Dropbox/programowanie/project_firefox/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/martyna/Dropbox/programowanie/project_firefox/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/martyna/Dropbox/programowanie/project_firefox/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/martyna/Dropbox/programowanie/project_firefox/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/martyna/Dropbox/programowanie/project_firefox/hello.py", line 46, in upload
    filenum = int(number[0]) + 1
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Comment: Please, provide full error trace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably, there is no element in your `Records` table. Therefore, `cur.fetchone()` returns `None` so you're effectively trying to access `None[0]`, hence the error message.

The error message by the way is telling you that you take `[0]` of something which is `None`, so if you look at the line, the only thing that you're taking `[0]` of is `number`. So a good way to debug such problems is to add something like `print number` before the offending line, this often challenges some fundamental believes I have about the contents of my variables :)

Comment: You are right. Somehow my data from database was deleted and I was refering to something that doesnt exist